# "Pythonic" equivalent term for code written in modern C++ style?

Tags: c++, terminology

There's a lot of good idioms promoted in modern C++. These include RAII and elegant use of boost or STL or a `std::algorithm` to solve a given problem.

Just like you can write C in any language, you can certainly write C in C++. However you can write really good  modern C++ code with the right subset of features. When someone does something really cool with an STL or boost construct I always get the urge to call it "pythonic" in the sense that its the canocical elegant way to do something. Is there a term like how "pythonic" is used in python to refer to C++ code written in the modern style with modern idioms?

Comment: How about bjarnic?

Comment: Anything wrong with "idiomatic C++ code"?

Comment: @delnan, maybe but I wish there was something more catchy! You could also say "idiomatic python code".

Comment: "Idiomatic" as in a idiom native to the language.

Comment: If such a term exists, it assumes that there is a single canonical way to do something in C++... My experience with C++ is that there are many different canonical / idiomatic ways to do the same thing, so I would doubt there's a special word for it.

Comment: Take a term from the 'hacker' community and call it 1337 (leet). Such a term also continues the C programmers reputation ;)

Comment: @OptimizePrime, when I hear code described as 1337, I get nervous that its probably too clever :)

Comment: @OptimizePrime That would be rather contraproductive, as professionality and cleverness are the last terms I would associate with someone speaking leetspeak.

Comment: @DougT - I completely agree.  My tongue in cheek comment was a throw back to my university days, of which the first year was complete confusion about what 1337 meant.

Comment: @ChristianRau I also agree with this, to carry on leetspeak beyond university is some what childish.  Just though I'd take a trip down memory lane.  Not that I used the lexicon myself, I just found it amusing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually call it "modern C++" and most people get what I mean by that.

Comment: Maybe for c++0x we should invent a new term, we can say the code r0x.

Comment: and mostly they run away, screaming?

Comment: "most people think they get what I think I mean by that"

Answer (score 6):

"Modern C++" as Nemanja Trifunovic already answered is well used, but **the generic adjective for all languages is "idiomatic"**. So for C++ it would be "idiomatic C++". "Pythonic way" is the same as "idiomatic Python".

Answer (score 4):

Nice question. Some of it seems to be covered by *idiomatic* as a more general version of *pythonic*; often *generic* code fits your requirements for *modern C++* in practice.

Especially as opposed to this C-style of code, I also often call that good code simply "C++" ;)

Answer (score -4):

'Slick' is a term I've used and heard for many years to describe clever, concise, well written code - from before Python was invented.